# How to create a django User with Django REST Framework (DRF) 3

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use Django Rest Framework 3.1.1 to create a user in a POST. I need to use the built-in method to create the encrypted password so I've tried to override the save method on the ModelSerializer but I clearly don't know Django / DRF well enough to do this. Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

When I try the code below, I get an error:

```
unbound method set_password() must be called with User instance as first argument (got unicode instance
```

instead)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def save(self):
        email = self.validated_data['email']
        username = self.validated_data['username']
        password = User.set_password(self.validated_data['password'])
```

Comment: set_password is an instance method, not a class/static method ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing something like this instead:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            email=validated_data['email']
            username=validated_data['username'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: It's better override the `update` method too, like says in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586095/why-isnt-my-django-user-models-password-hashed/27586289. If override just the `create` method, is possible that some tools with `curl` or some external application get `500 error` in the `POST` operation on API from client.

Comment: @bgarcial, I don't follow what you're trying to say. It doesn't matter what client the request comes from..if it's a POST, this should work.

Answer (score 3):

**Since you are using a `ModelSerializer`, you can override the `perform_create()` function in your view and then set the password for the user.**

DRF has provided this hook to add some custom actions which should occur before or after saving an object.

As per [DRF3 documentation:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview)

> These override points are particularly useful for adding behavior
>   that occurs before or after saving an object, such as emailing a
>   confirmation, or logging the update.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class MyView(..):

    ...

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        hashed_password = make_password(serializer.validated_data['password']) # get the hashed password
        serializer.validated_data['password'] = hashed_password 
        user = super(MyView, self).perform_create(serializer) # create a user
```

Since, Django stores the password in hashed format and not as raw passwords, we use Django's [`make_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password) to get the raw password in hashed format. We then set the `password` in `validated_data` of the serializer to this hashed password. This hashed password is then used by the serializer when creating the user by calling the `super()`.