# updating user profile using django rest framework api

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I want to create an API where user can update their profile. In my case, a user can update his/her username and password. To change his/her profile, an API link should be `/api/change/usernameOfThatUser`. When I use a non-existing username in the link, I still get the userProfileChange API page, and the input boxes are not filled with previous data. How can I solve this?

**serializers.py**

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserProfileChangeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, initial="current username")
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username',instance.username)
        print('instance of username',instance.username)
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class UserProfileChangeAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileChangeSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
```

**urls.py**

```
  url(r'^change/(?P<username>[\w-]+)$', UserProfileChangeAPIView.as_view(), name='changeProfile'),
```

Comment: What you want to happen when you use non existed username in the link?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. "How can i solve this?" << you need to tell us what behavior is expected here because the one you have is the one I'd expect.

Comment: suppose my username is michael then what i want is if i want to change my username then i would do /api/users/michael and the page will be shown with username field and password field. In username field, my name will be already filled in, i would then edit it and save.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe try doing something like this instead in your **views.py**?

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins, permissions

User = get_user_model()

class UserIsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.id == request.user.id

class UserProfileChangeAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView,
                               mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                               mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
        UserIsOwnerOrReadOnly,
    )
    serializer_class = UserProfileChangeSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs["username"]
        obj = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        return obj

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This will give you all of the existing data for the user based on the username passed in the url. If the username does not exist, it will raise a 404 error. You can also update or delete the object.

Comment: Password is shown in sha256$24000$ form. How can i show empty box only for password? Any authenticated user can open the profile edit page of other user. So can you enlighten me the concept to solve this?

Comment: @pri If you take a look at the code now, it will make sure the user can only edit their own profile. It was a permission change. I would create a separate function for password change functionality. Do you need help with that as well?

Comment: @pri You can take a look at this for hashing the password: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586095/why-isnt-my-django-user-models-password-hashed

Comment: Thanks I will look at hashing the password.