# creating users with Django REST Framework - not authenticate

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, restful-authentication, password-encryption

I am working with Django users, and I've hashed the passwords when I create an user with `Django REST Framework` and I override the `create` and `update` methods on my serializer to hash my passwords users

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #username = models.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            if attr == 'password':
                instance.set_password(value)
            else:
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'password', 'first_name','last_name',
                  'age', 'sex', 'photo', 'email', 'is_player', 'team',
                  'position', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser',
                  'is_player', 'weight', 'height', 'nickname',
                  'number_matches', 'accomplished_matches',
                  'time_available', 'leg_profile', 'number_shirt_preferred',
                  'team_support', 'player_preferred', 'last_login',
        )
```

My views.py is this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_fields = ('username', 'is_player', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'team' , 'email', )
```

My REST_FRAMEWORK settings are:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),

    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

The inconvenient that I have is that when I create and user via rest framework, the password is hashed, but I cannot sign in or login via rest authentication and Django admin too.

How to can I hash my passwords and sign in via Djago REST FRamework too?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add rest framework authentication setting with following also

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ( 
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', 
)
```

Ref http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication

And for token autentication go through doc http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication